# How to print excel data with Lua

Tags: excel, lua

I'm trying to print some excel datas, but I just receive "table" in output.

Below is my code, that connect with plan (in example "Plantest").

```
    require('luacom')
    excel = luacom.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    excel.Visible = true

    fpath = "C:\\Documents\\Planteste.xlsx"
    wb = excel.Workbooks:Open(fpath)
    ws = wb.Worksheets("Plan1")
```

To print I try:

```
Value = excel.Cells(1, 1)
```

But in output I receive table.

How can I print a specific row?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

print(ws.Cells(1, 1).Value(""))

Show the content from "A1" cell.

:)

Thank